# make an object the exact copy of another

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have these two object:

[image: objects]

the selected ico sphere is called flame.001, the "distorted" ico sphere is called flame.002 . I want flame.001 to be the exact copy of flame.002 in terms of shape. I don't want to change material, texture or any other stuff than shape. How can I achieve this? It would be great if there is a modifier that can make the ico sphere approximate the other object based on a given value e.g. with value 0 I have an ico sphere, with value 1 I have the exact copy of the shape on the right, with 0.5 I have something in between.

Comment: I had given an incomplete answer. I would recommend you following some 'shape key' tutorials. This is what you are looking for.
I won't suggest using a modifier for this as shapekeys are specially designed for this kind of stuff.

Comment: when you say "I don't want to change material, texture or any other stuff than shape" you mean just shape or shape and topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both objects have the same topology then you can add the shape of one object as a shape key to the original object. The shape key's influence then can be seamlessly varied to “morph” between the two shapes.

1. Select the **second mesh**
2. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting the the **first mesh**
3. In the **Properties** window under **Data** > **Shape Keys** in the drop down menu click on **Join as Shapes**

[image: Join as Shapes]

This method does not work if the topology isn't the same, i.e. if you've added additional vertices.

Answer (score 1):

If the two objects have the same number of vertices then you can use the Data Transfer modifier shown below:

[image]

Comment: @JoulinRouge note that the two objects should have same amount of vertices, for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wish those two spheres objects to have identical shape the best method is to let one object to use the same mesh of the other. How?

Let's start with two very different basic shapes:a cube and a sphere.

[image]

You see, the "cube" object has a "cube" mesh, while the "sphere" object has a "sphere" mesh.

But you can assign a different mesh to any object, and also share them between different objects. Let's pick the cube, now

[image]

and change its mesh, setting it to the same "sphere" mesh of the "sphere" object:

[image]

now that's a strange "cube", isn't it? Note the "sphere"mesh "users" count of 2! Yes, both objects use the same mesh.

And you can also make the opposite, pick the "sphere" object , and assign it the "cube" mesh.

[image]

The downside is that the material is a mesh property... and thus you'll get the same material for both objects... but you can "solve" this, as it follows.

You can make the shared "sphere" mesh to become two independent "sphere" mesh, just click on the "2" little button, and you'll get this:

[image]

And now you can assign different materials to "sphere" and"sphere.001", as they are completely independent now.

[image]

Wonderful! Hth.